# How large is Al Amarja?

Tags: maps, over-the-edge

What are the physical dimensions of the island of Al Amarja, and its population? Any other specific information, such as other towns on the island, would be welcome.

Comment: Ive added the maps tag, since its the closest tag we have to general geography questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their [map](https://www.atlas-games.com/pdf_storage/AlAmarjaMap11x17WEB.pdf) available for download, the only major cities seem to be The Edge and Freedom City on the opposite coast. There are additionally 4 Resorts, indicating that there is habitation between the two, but it seems to be up to GM's to fill in their version of Al Amarja.

According to their [map](https://www.atlas-games.com/atlas-cms/resources/downloads/ote3-mapoftheedge.jpg) of The Edge, and more specifically the call-out of the island, there is also a notable location named Skylla in the north.

There are no scales availabe in either map, nor the [Geography section of "Over the Edge Setting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over_the_Edge_(game)#Setting),

> Al Amarja is an independent island state in the southern Mediterranean. The western side of the island is covered by three interconnected cities (from north to south): the port town of Skylla, the slums of The Edge and the tract housing of suburban Traboc. Most of the population lives there.

> **Freedom City, the capital of Al Amarja, is on the eastern end of the island and was based on Washington D.C.** It consists mainly of stately government buildings and the opulent homes of government officials, surrounded by the rickety slums that house the government employees. The only difference between Washington D.C. and Freedom City is here the drug dens and brothels are in the good part of town and are very exclusive.

> The two ends of the island are linked by the "October 7th Memorial Highway" along the northern coast and "Freedom Road" along the southern coast. The rest of the island is undeveloped hilly forest, at the center of which lies an extinct volcano called Mount Ralsius.

> The French version of the game (called Conspirations) shifted the position of Al Amarja to the Caribbean for the same reasons it was placed in the Mediterranean sea in the original: an exotic place in an area of numerous islands sufficiently unfamiliar to the target audience, next to big western nations where many cultures and societies mix.

If we are to assume the section I bolded is literally accurate, [Washington DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.#Geography) we can estimate the size of the island based on DC's dimensions. The metropolitan area around it is approx 40 miles wide (Beltsville, VA to Newington, VA) while the DC proper is a little under 16 top-left corner to bottom-right. Based on 16 miles, the island would be ~85 miles wide (straight line at the middle) and 43-45 miles tall, or approx. 3,750 sq. miles, assuming the first map is to scale. Alternatively, if you use the metropolitan sizing, it would be ~214x105(-115) miles (approx. 23,500 sq. mi.).

Based on the handy [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_area) @HeyICanChan provided, this puts it around the size of Puerto Rico or Lebanon (small) to almost exactly the size of Svalbard, Norway or a bit smaller (about 10%) than Ireland (large).